# How to enforce planetary gravity on fluids?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to make a scene with a few small planets, but when I went to make a lake/river I couldn't find any options to have the fluid's gravity be relative to a point (aka the planet's center). I've tried putting a forcefield at the center of my planet but the fluids just seem to ignore it completely even if it works for rigidbody objects. Would it even be practical to do my lakes this way, or would it be better if I made a mesh to fill the lake instead of bothering with fluid simulation?

Comment: A fluid simulation in Blender is probably not the best tool for your purpose. A simple geometry with the appropriate textures (displacement) would work. There is also the ocean modifier.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I never would have thought about the ocean modifier.

Comment: I initially thought a fluid 'Control' object might do the trick (with gravity disabled) but having tried it the force doesn't fall off - it attracts to the mesh (the planet core) but at full strength as soon as the fluid reaches the radius. If fluid control objects could specify a falloff for the force based on distance then I'm convinced that would offer a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use particles set to 'Fluid' type and rendered using a Metaball as the dupli-object. While this won't produce a full fluid simulation it might be good enough for your usage. Using particles means that the 'fluid' will be affected by the force fields (the true fluid simulation is not affected by such force fields) so you can disable gravity and use a force to draw the 'fluid' to the planet.

This can produce the following :

[image: fluid planet]

Blend file included [image]